# Why is lifecycleScope not responding in Activity Class?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

When I click on an item in the category RecycleView (categoryRecyclerView), which is responsible for the category, the classification code changes.
After that, the goal is to regenerate recyclerView accordingly from goodsRecyclerView.

The first time you run it, it's exactly called, but it doesn't reflect when you change the category.

In ViewModel, _selectSubDispClasSeq is a category classification code and I want to reflect it in _goods.

---

Below is my code.

@AndroidEntryPoint
class DetailCategoryActivity : BaseActivity({ ActivityDetailCategoryBinding.inflate(it)}) {

```
private val viewModel: DetailCategoryViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val dispClasSeq = intent.getIntExtra("dispClasSeq", 0)

    val categoryRecyclerView = binding.rvSublistCategory
    val categoryLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3)

    val categoryAdapter = SubListAdapter(emptyList()) { selectedDispClasItem ->
        viewModel.onSubItemClicked(selectedDispClasItem)
    }

    categoryRecyclerView.adapter = categoryAdapter
    categoryRecyclerView.layoutManager = categoryLayoutManager


    val goodsRecyclerView = binding.rvGoods
    val goodsLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)

    val goodsAdapter = GoodsAdapter()
    goodsRecyclerView.adapter = goodsAdapter
    goodsRecyclerView.layoutManager = goodsLayoutManager

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.subDispClasInfos.collect { subDispClasInfos ->
            viewModel.loadSubDispClasInfos(dispClasSeq)
            categoryAdapter.submitList(subDispClasInfos)
        }
    }

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.goods.collect { goods ->
            Log.d("goods", goods.toString())
            val subDsipClasSeq = viewModel.selectedSubDispClasSeq.value
            viewModel.loadGoodsInfos(dispClasSeq, subDsipClasSeq, "추천순")
            goodsAdapter.submitData(goods)
        }
    }

}
```

}

```
@HiltViewModel
```

class DetailCategoryViewModel @Inject constructor(
private val detailItemRepository: DetailItemRepository,
private val goodsItemRepository: GoodsItemRepository
) : ViewModel() {

```
private val _subDispClasInfos = MutableStateFlow<List<DetailCategoryItem>>(emptyList())
val subDispClasInfos: StateFlow<List<DetailCategoryItem>> get() = _subDispClasInfos

private val _goods: MutableStateFlow<PagingData<Goods>> = MutableStateFlow(PagingData.empty())
val goods: StateFlow<PagingData<Goods>> get() = _goods

private val _selectedSubDispClasSeq = MutableStateFlow(0)
val selectedSubDispClasSeq: StateFlow<Int> get() = _selectedSubDispClasSeq

fun loadSubDispClasInfos(dispClasSeq: Int) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            detailItemRepository.getCategorySublistItemsFlow(dispClasSeq).collect { result ->
                _subDispClasInfos.emit(result)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("result", e.toString())
        }
    }
}

fun loadGoodsInfos(prntsDispClasSeq: Int, subDispClasSeq: Int, searchValue: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            Log.d("loadGoodsInfos1", subDispClasSeq.toString())
            val result = goodsItemRepository.getGoodsItemsFlow(prntsDispClasSeq, subDispClasSeq, searchValue)
                .first()
            _goods.emit(result)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("result", e.toString())
        }
    }
}

fun onSubItemClicked(item: DetailCategoryItem) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _selectedSubDispClasSeq.emit(item.dispClasSeq)
        loadGoodsInfos(item.prntsDispClasSeq, selectedSubDispClasSeq.value, "추천순")
    }
}
```

}

When I output the log, it was confirmed that the value of _selectedSubDispClasSeq changed normally in the loadGoodsInfos function. But I couldn't observe it in the activity class.

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.goods.collect { goods ->
            Log.d("goods", goods.toString())
            val subDsipClasSeq = viewModel.selectedSubDispClasSeq.value
            viewModel.loadGoodsInfos(dispClasSeq, subDsipClasSeq, "추천순")
            goodsAdapter.submitData(goods)
        }
    }
```